# Why is image_read in R running faster on subsequent runs?

Tags: r, performance

I have written code in several different ways to try and improve performance (e.g., custom loops), so I will use the simplest example.

Sample data:

```
PHOTO_FULL_URL

https://media.ci.org/v1622888316/ChildPhotos/Published/09143775_omazho.jpg
https://media.ci.org/v1645477744/ChildPhotos/Published/09222560_pirqui.jpg
https://media.ci.org/v1639495453/ChildPhotos/Published/05016641_e459db.jpg
https://media.ci.org/v1620240491/ChildPhotos/Published/05079484_d89f93.jpg
```

Simple code:

```
ptm <- proc.time()
test <- sapply(raw_data$PHOTO_FULL_URL,image_read)
print(proc.time() - ptm)
```

The initial run of this code is always about 50-70% longer than subsequent runs:

```
Trial   1    2    3    1    2    3
Rows    10   10   10   20   20   20 
Seconds 4.14 0.88 0.85 6.08 1.75 1.64
```

Why does this happen, and how can I capitalize on the performance improvement of the subsequent runs?

Comment: This is probably OS-level caching of the download (and/or local file) data. This is normal and expected but you don’t generally have any control over it, unless you structure your data dependencies in such a way to maximise cache locality. In a language like R I generally wouldn’t try, too many things over which you have no control can influence this.

Comment: Thanks, @KonradRudolph. If you frame this as an answer, I can accept it.